# Find an replace in xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to replace values in this xml, what I want to replace is this ip 10.10.10.75 all occurrences.

```
    <profile name="internal">
    <settings>
     <param name="rtp-ip" value="10.10.10.75"/>
        <!-- ip address to bind to, DO NOT USE HOSTNAMES ONLY IP ADDRESSES -->
        <param name="sip-ip" value="10.10.10.75"/>
    <param name="presence-hosts" value="10.10.10.75,10.10.10.75"/>

 </settings>
</profile>
```

This is my sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from shutil import copyfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#try:

#       copyfile('/usr/src/sample.xml','/usr/src/sample3.xml')
#       print "Profile Copied Sucessfully"

#except IOError as e:
#    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)

with open('/usr/src/sample3.xml') as f:
  tree = ET.parse(f)
  root = tree.getroot()

  for elem in root.getiterator():
    try:
      elem.text = elem.text.replace('10.10.10.75', '10.10.10.100')
    #  elem.text = elem.text.replace('FEATURE NUMBER', '123456')
    except AttributeError:
      pass

tree.write('/usr/src/sample3.xml')
```

This not getting what I want and it's removing commented lines also which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace occurrences, why don't you just treat it as string?

```
with open('/usr/src/sample3.xml') as f:
    xml_str = f.read()
xml_str = xml_str.replace('10.10.10.75', '10.10.10.100')

with open('/usr/src/sample3.xml', "w") as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
from lxml import etree
import os

xml_file = "/usr/src/sample.xml"
xml_file_output = '{}_out.xml'.format(os.path.splitext(xml_file)[0])

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=False)
tree = etree.parse(xml_file, parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for param in root.iter("param"):
    replaced_ip = param.get("value").replace("10.10.10.75", "10.10.10.100")
    param.set("value", replaced_ip)

tree.write(xml_file_output)
```

**EDIT**

I configured the parser so comments are not removed.